# PhpStorm : Combine multiple lines by using icons

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, php-ide

Normally on notepad there are some icons which allow us to combine multiple lines of code to end up having only one line.

[image]

I am using PhpStorm 10.0.1, is there any way for me to get this option.

Kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: This is called "folding" code, not "combining" it, and you should already have similar icons on your screen in PHPStorm. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/code-folding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm has the same thing.

[image]

Click on the [image] to collapse the block of code. Then click on [image] to expand it.

This is explained in more detail in the documentation on [code folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/code-folding.html)

If you don't see these icons, go to `Preferences > Editor > General > Code Folding` and enable `Show code folding outline`.

Comment: Thanks for answering but on my PhpStorm, the icons do not appear

Comment: I've been using PhpStorm for many years, and they have always shown.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the preference item that controls it.

Comment: Thanks, the icons appears now but I need to hover them before they can be shown. Is there any way to display them by default ?

Comment: They appear by default for me, I don't know why it's different for you.

Comment: Maybe you should open a case with JetBrains tech support. They've always been very helpful to me.

Comment: The problem is faced was because of the theme I was using. Thanks.